# Python Multiprocessing password cracker

Tags: python, multithreading, passwords, multicore, cracking

I have been learning Python in my spare time for a small amount of time now and I set myself a challenge to build a password cracker for a very specific task, it was to test how effective the security on my ADSL Router was (not very) - using Wireshark I could quite clearly see how it was hashing the password over http and I developed some code to perform a wordlist attack. (I apologise if you think my code is badly written - you would probably be correct!).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import hashlib, os, time, math
from hashlib import md5

def screen_clear():
    if os.name == 'nt':
        return os.system('cls')
    else:
        return os.system('clear')

screen_clear()

print ""
print "Welcome to the Technicolor md5 cracker"
print ""

user = raw_input("Username: ")
print ""
nonce = raw_input("Nonce: ")
print ""
hash = raw_input("Hash: ")
print ""
file = raw_input("Wordlist: ")
print ""

realm = "Technicolor Gateway"
qop = "auth"
uri = "/login.lp"

HA2 = md5("GET" + ":" + uri).hexdigest()

wordlist = open(file, 'r')

time1 = time.time()

for word in wordlist:
    pwd = word.replace("\n","") 
    HA1 = md5(user + ":" + realm + ":" + pwd).hexdigest()
    hidepw = md5(HA1 + ":" + nonce +":" + "00000001" + ":" + "xyz" + ":" + qop + ":" + HA2).hexdigest()
    if hidepw == hash:
        screen_clear()
        time2 = time.time()
        timetotal = math.ceil(time2 - time1)
        print pwd + " = " + hidepw + " (in " + str(timetotal) + " seconds)"
        print ""
        end = raw_input("hit enter to exit")
        exit()

wordlist.close()

screen_clear()
time2 = time.time()
totaltime = math.ceil(time2 - time1)
print "Sorry, out of " + str(tested) + " passwords tested, your password was not found (in " + str(totaltime) + " seconds)"
print ""
end = raw_input("hit enter to exit")
screen_clear()
exit()
```

This works well enough but has left me wanting more, so I thought I could add some Multiprocessing power to it to speed things up - using various different instructions and guides I have failed to end up with a successful result! (although feeling like i was very close)

Please could someone either point me towards "An idiots guide to multicore python password cracking" or help my modify my code to suit.

P.S. my original plan was to use opencl or cuda...but I quickly learned how out of my depth I was!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made an example for you that should be relatively easy to add into your code.  Here is how it works; First, we need to brake up the `wordlist` into manageable chunks that we can throw into the multiprocessor module.  I do this by making a list with a dictionary of 'starting' and 'stopping' points.  Next, I pass those arguments into `apply_async` which will in turn run the `pwd_find` function.  This is the function you want to add your `for word in wordlist:` loop, but with a starting and stopping point (see code below).

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import math
import time

cores = 4  # Number of cores to use
wordlist = []

for i in range(127):  # Remove this for your own word list.
    wordlist.append(str(i))  # Creates a large 'word' list for testing.

def pwd_find(start, stop):

    for word in range(start, stop):
        print(wordlist[word])
        time.sleep(0.1)  # Slows things down so it's easier to see that your system is using more than one core.
        ### Add your code here... ###


break_points = []  # List that will have start and stopping points
for i in range(cores):  # Creates start and stopping points based on length of word list
    break_points.append({"start":math.ceil(len(wordlist)/cores * i), "stop":math.ceil(len(wordlist)/cores * (i + 1))})

if __name__ == '__main__':  # Added this because the multiprocessor module acts funny without it.

    p = Pool(cores)  # Number of processors to utilize.
    for i in break_points:  # Cycles though the breakpoints list created above.
        print(i)  # shows the start and stop points.
        a = p.apply_async(pwd_find, kwds=i, args=tuple())  # This will start the separate processes.
    print("Done!")
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

If your code finds a match, add `p.terminate` followed by `p.join` to kill the processors.

If you would like to lean more about the multiprocessor module, [go here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) to learn more.

I hope this helps you out, or at the very least, gives you a better insight into multiprocessing!

Comment: That you very much for the detailed answer, due to work commitments I haven't had time to get back home to try this out, I will be sure to let you know of my success on my return!

Comment: Spent the evening getting my code to work, and it is now giving me a correct answer (will now compare to see how much quicker it is)! thanks for your help - you explained just enough for me to still do some thinking! one problem was that the dictionary contained an float intead of an integer (easily solved) but took me a while to work out how to output any error from within the apply_async processes ( print (a.get()) ) - it was all very interesting and i have certainly learned a lot

Comment: Just to follow this up, it just about halfed the time needed to run through the entire "rockyou.txt" wordlist on my hyperthreaded dual core laptop! Fantastic.

Comment: hi @Andy, could you please post entire code ? It's useful to learning. Or a github link :)

Comment: It would be much easier to use `pool.map(f, wordlist)`. It splits the iterable (wordlist in this case) between threads, then runs the function on the sections. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map