# Adding multiprocessing to existing Python script?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, cracking

I'm trying to add multiprocessing to an existing password cracker, the source of which is located here: https://github.com/axcheron/pyvboxdie-cracker

The script works great but it's really slow, adding multiprocessing will certainly speed it up. I've looked online (and on here) for some examples and I've hit a wall of complete information overload, I just can't get my head around it. I found a really helpful post on here by the user Camon (posted here: [Python Multiprocessing password cracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33456511/python-multiprocessing-password-cracker)) but I can't see how I can implement it in the script.

```
def crack_keystore(keystore, dict):

wordlist = open(dict, 'r')
hash = get_hash_algorithm(keystore)
count = 0

print("\n[*] Starting bruteforce...")

for line in wordlist.readlines():

    kdf1 = PBKDF2HMAC(algorithm=hash, length=keystore['Key_Length'], salt=keystore['Salt1_PBKDF2'],
                      iterations=keystore['Iteration1_PBKDF2'], backend=backend)

    aes_key = kdf1.derive(line.rstrip().encode())

    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(aes_key), modes.XTS(tweak), backend=backend)
    decryptor = cipher.decryptor()

    aes_decrypt = decryptor.update(keystore['Enc_Password'])

    kdf2 = PBKDF2HMAC(algorithm=hash, length=keystore['KL2_PBKDF2'], salt=keystore['Salt2_PBKDF2'],
                      iterations=keystore['Iteration2_PBKDF2'], backend=backend)

    final_hash = kdf2.derive(aes_decrypt)

    if random.randint(1, 20) == 12:
        print("\t%d password tested..." % count)
    count += 1

    if binascii.hexlify(final_hash).decode() == binascii.hexlify(keystore['Final_Hash'].rstrip(b'\x00')).decode():
        print("\n[*] Password Found = %s" % line.rstrip())
        exit(0)

print("\t[-] Password Not Found. You should try another dictionary.")
```

This is the part of the script that I need to edit, the example by Carmon has a function to split the wordlist into chunks and each process is given it's own chunk. The problem I have implementing it, is that the wordlist is only populated inside the function (after other tasks have been completed, full source on repo). How would I implement multiprocessing to this section? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of an entire repo. Also, this is a VERY open ended question. What are you asking for exactly? Resources to understand multiprocessing in Python? Simple introductions?

Answer (score 1):

```
from multiprocessing import Process

# keystore = some_value
# dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4

proc_1 = Process(target=crack_keystore, args=(keystore, dict1))
proc_2 = Process(target=crack_keystore, args=(keystore, dict2))
proc_3 = Process(target=crack_keystore, args=(keystore, dict3))
proc_4 = Process(target=crack_keystore, args=(keystore, dict4))

proc_1.start()
proc_2.start()
proc_3.start()
proc_4.start()

proc_1.join()
proc_2.join()
proc_3.join()
proc_4.join()

print("All processes successfully ended!")
```

The maximum count of processes must not be more than the count of cores of your CPU.